# Extracting string from string

Tags: c, string

I want to extract from string containing a mathematical operation , the   operands and operators and put its in the array "op"

```
char ch[20]="25+66*888/58=";
int i=0,j=0,k=0;
char op[10][5];

while((ch[i]!='='))
{  
   j=0;
   while((ch[i]!='+') &&
         (ch[i]!='-') &&
         (ch[i]!='*') &&
         (ch[i]!='/') &&      
         (ch[i]!='=')))
   {
      op[k][j]=ch[i];
      j++;
      i++;
   }
   k++;
   op[k][0]=ch[i];
   k++;

   if (j==0) 
      i++;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? And why is op a 2-dimensional array?

Comment: op contains Strings so that his dimension is 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code ectract operation and operands

```
char ch[20]="25+66*888/58=";
    char operands[10][5], operators[10];
    int j=0, i=0, k=0, l=0;

     while(ch[i])
     {
        if((ch[i]!='+')&&(ch[i]!='-')&&(ch[i]!='*')&&(ch[i]!='/')&&(ch[i]!='='))
        {
            operands[k][j]=ch[i];
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            operators[l]=ch[i];
            l++;
            k++;
            j=0;
        }
        i++;
     }

     for(i=0;i<l;i++) cout<< operators[i];
     cout<<endl;

     for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
     {
        for(int j=0;operands[i][j];j++)
        {
            cout<<operands[i][j];
         }
         cout<<" ";
     }
```

Comment: what do u mean by "cout<<"  it didn't work(but i changed it to standar output using printf) ,and i want to ask why if i type printf("%s ",operands[i]) won't work ?

Comment: I use c++, cout, cin are operators of c++. array operands is two-dimensional array. operands[i][j] is work.

Comment: Unfortunally ,I'm using C ,and as I said I typed printf("%s ",operands[i]) ,it should work because "operands[i]" is string, but the compiler seems to fail to recognize the lenght of the string .